# Is it possible that key has multi values on Lua script

Tags: lua

I want to handle lua table.

Script:

```
local my_talbe = {}

for key, value in pairs(my_table)
 print(key, value)
end
```

The script returns:

```
a 80
b 80
c 70
d 40
e 70
f 80
```

I want to my_table handle like this:

```
local new_talbe = {}

for key, value in pairs(new_table)
 print(key, value)
end
```

Expected output:

```
80 {a,b,f} # table
70 {c,e}
40 {d}
```

Please help me.

Comment: just `new_table[80] = { 'a', 'b', 'f' }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can change how `my_table` is created, use @pynexj method.

If you need to convert, something like this should do the job.

```lua
local my_table = {
    a = 80,
    b = 80,
    c = 70,
    d = 40,
    e = 70,
    f =  80,
}

-- Invert key and value, but put the keys into buckets/arrays
local function to_multi_key_map(t)
    local n = { }
    for i,v in pairs(t) do
        if n[v] then
            table.insert(n[v], i)
        else
            n[v] = { i }
        end
    end
    return n
end

for i,v in pairs(to_multi_key_map(my_table)) do
    print(i, "{" .. table.concat(v, ", ") .. "}")
end
```

```
70  {c, e}
80  {b, f, a}
40  {d}
```

Comment: a variation of this would be to do `n[v] = n[v] or {}` removing the need for that if else